# Python equivalent to TypeScript type unions?

Tags: python, python-typing

In TypeScript you can create a type defined by a set of particular elements:

```
type Context = '2d' | 'webgl' | 'webgl2'

class CanvasFacade {
  constructor(ctx: Context) {}
}
```

Are there any recommended ways to achieve this in Python? Presumably using libraries such as `typing`? Enums?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So would I do `Context = Union['2d', 'webgl', 'webgl2']`, then `ctx: Context`?

Comment: That's not even valid TypeScript.

Comment: I think you'd probably want to use `typing.Literal` here depending on what you are doing. A *union* you can do with `typing.Union` or with the `|` operator, but I guess in typescript `"2d"` is implicitly a string literal type, in Pyhton, you have to use `typing.Literal`. You *could* also use an enum if you wanted (I would generally prefer that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), for general unions. However, in Python, literal string types are not written as strings, so the type called `'2d'` in Typescript is equivalent to `Literal['2d']` in Python, where [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) is also from `typing`.

```
Union[Literal['2d'], Literal['webgl'], Literal['webgl2']]
```

Now, if you're using Python 3.10 or newer, you can benefit from [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/), which allows writing union types with the bitwise-or operator.

```
Literal['2d'] | Literal['webgl'] | Literal['webgl2']
```

Finally, because this "union of literals" pattern is so common, the `Literal` type supports it directly.

```
Literal['2d', 'webgl', 'webgl2']
```